# Difference between 'fmap' and 'flatMap', if any

Tags: javascript, dictionary, functor, flatmap

Every resource I've found so far compares *map* and *flatMap*.
That is *not* my intention.

In this YouTube video about functional programming in javascript (particularly around 12:27), the speaker shows an example of `fmap`ing over a `Maybe` functor. All is well and good so far. What confuses me is the `mjoin`, and the speaker's comment about how `flatMap` (not `fmap`) is simply a composition of `fmap` and `mjoin`.

This confuses me because up until now I have used the names `fmap` and `flatMap` interchangeably, although this talk implies they are not the same thing.

For a concrete question, I would like to know if this is implementation specific, or are `fmap` and `flatMap` actually two different things, in the context of functional programming? If they are different, what does the `f` in `fmap` stand for if it is not flat?

Its still fuzzy in my head, but the first thing that comes to mind is that `flatMap` will map over a functor, producing nested functors, which is then flattened into a single functor (or at least one level up). In contrast, `fmap`'s function parameter will return a single functor, which does not need to be flattened.

Maybe I'm close, or way off. Anyone in the FP world care to shed some light?

The video mentioned above.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AvgwKjTPMmM

### *Edit*

If they are different, does `f` in `fmap` translate to *functor map*?
Best guess.
Although functors implement map, so technically every `map` is acting on some type of functor.
Please. Clear. Hazy. Brain.

Comment: `fmap` is `map`. `f` stands for functor afaik.

Comment: Haha, so my first statement was wrong...

Comment: And yes! I had the lightbulb moment of functor at the last second, check the Edit. Although that still raises the question, isn't every `map` method acting on a functor of some sort?

Comment: Yes, functors must implement a `map`, that's what makes them functors. Monads must implement `flatMap`, that's what makes them monads. A monad is a functor.

Comment: I guess `fmap` (`Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b`) was chosen in Haskell, because `map` (`(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`) was already taken. `flatMap` maps a function over a collection and flattens the result by one level. It's a way to implement the composition operator for monads. But you should stick to the Javascript terms anyway: `map` and `chain`.